# Redux wont remove item from state array by ID

Tags: reactjs, redux

I dont understant what is wrong with this code, im passing in ID and filtering out state, but it just wont remove, cant figure it out, would love some help.
slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movie",
  initialState: { favoriteMovies: [] },
  reducers: {
    addMovie: (state, action) => {
      state.favoriteMovies = [...state.favoriteMovies, action.payload];
    },
    removeMovie: (state, action) => {
      state.favoriteMovies = state.favoriteMovies.filter(
        (movie) => movie.imdbID !== action.payload
      );
    },
  },
});

export const { addMovie, removeMovie } = movieSlice.actions;
export const selectMovie = (state) => state.movie.favoriteMovies;

export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

dispatching:

```
const MovieDetail = ({ movie }) => {
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const imdbID = movie.imdbID;

  const handleAddFavorite = () => {
    dispatch(addMovie({ movie }));
    setIsFavorite(true);
  };
  const handleRemoveFavorite = () => {
    dispatch(removeMovie({ imdbID }));
    console.log(imdbID);
    setIsFavorite(false);
  };
```

it does nothing when should remove, and then add it again. The ids i pass in are correct.

Comment: Move your console.log into the `removeMovie` reducer. `action.payload` isn't what you think it is

Comment: @chazsolo o I see now, i should be using action.payload.imdbID, but it still does not remove the item from state

Comment: @Daniels0n do the same while adding movie to favoriteMovies array - `action.payload.movie`. Otherwise, while removing, movie.imdbID would be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are dispatching with

```js
    dispatch(removeMovie({ imdbID }));
```

`imdbID` will end up as `action.payload.imdbID`.

So you need to either access that, or dispatch like

```js
    dispatch(removeMovie(imdbID));
```